# How to solve this differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've got an equation

$$e^x(y^2-4y' -4y)=4y'$$

after some transformations, i recieve

$$y= \frac{-4}{e^x+C_2(x)}$$

$$y'=\frac{4(e^x+C'_2(x))}{(e^x+C_2(x))^2}$$
but when i add these equations to the first one $C_2(x)$ sill remains in equation.. Can somebody sole it?

Comment: What does $C_2(x)$ represent?  Should that just be an arbitrary *constant*, not an arbitrary *function*?

Comment: It is a Riccati type.

Comment: Arbitrary constant, i should have be more precise! sorry!

Comment: Observe that $y=4$ is a solution.

Comment: @Mikkey: This is a Separable Equation and you would have $$\displaystyle \int \dfrac{4}{y(y-4)}~ dy = \int \dfrac{e^x}{e^x + 1}~dx$$

Comment: @Moo yes, i recieved that. Thats from where I get $y'$ but what next? Can You expand your idea?

Comment: You would integrate using Partial Fractions on the left hand side and the right is straightforward.

Comment: Without the Cauchy condition you can't find the value od C, because the result of diferential equations is family of curves

Comment: @Mikkey, if $C_2$ is just a constant then you should say $C_2$ and not $C_2(x)$.  Also, since $C_2$ is a constant then $C_2' = 0$.

Comment: Okey, this was a problem, i treated C(x) as funtion not constant. I think is enough math for me today. Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comment discussion on the question, $C_2(x)$ should really be $C_2$ since $C_2$ is just a constant and does not depend on $x$.

You found $y(x) = \dfrac{-4}{e^x + C_2}$.

So then $y'(x) = \dfrac{(e^x + C_2)(0) - (-4)(e^x)}{(e^x + C_2)^2} = \dfrac{4e^x}{(e^x+C_2)^2}$

When you plug this into the LHS of the original equation, you get:

\begin{align*}
  e^x(y^2 - 4y' - 4y) &= e^x \left(\frac{16}{(e^x+C_2)^2} - \frac{16e^x}{(e^x+C_2)^2} + \frac{16}{e^x+C_2}\right)\\[0.3cm]
  &= e^x \left(\frac{16}{(e^x+C_2)^2} - \frac{16e^x}{(e^x+C_2)^2} + \frac{16(e^x+C_2)}{(e^x+C_2)^2}\right)\\[0.3cm]
  &= e^x \left(\frac{16}{(e^x+C_2)^2} - \frac{16e^x}{(e^x+C_2)^2} + \frac{16e^x}{(e^x+C_2)^2} + \frac{16C_2}{(e^x+C_2)^2}\right)\\[0.3cm]
  &= e^x \left(\frac{16}{(e^x+C_2)^2} + \frac{16C_2}{(e^x+C_2)^2}\right)\\[0.3cm]
  &= \frac{16e^x(1+C_2)}{(e^x+C_2)^2}
\end{align*}

But in the RHS, you get:
$$ 4y' = \frac{16e^x}{(e^x+C_2)^2}
$$

So very close, but these are not quite the same.  So your $y(x)$ isn't correct.